# How to pass inbuilt function as parameter in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I want to write a generic function to replace Null value with mean or median or drop the table,

```
def fill_null(df,col_name,action):
    df_tmp = df.apply(df[col_name].action())
    return df_tmp
if __name__ == '__main__':
    df_sal  =  pd.read_excel("sample_sal.xlsx")
    df = fill_null(df_sal,"Salary","mean")
    print(df)
```

error getting :

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'action'
```

I am able getting the output in following way, but that is not the req

```
if action == "mean":
  df[col_name].fillna(df[col_name].mean(), inplace=True)
  return df
elif action == "median":
  df[col_name].fillna(df[col_name].median(), inplace=True)
  return df
elif action == "drop":
  df = df.dropna(subset = [col_name])
  return df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.aggregate.html) or [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) working with aggregating functions:

```
def fill_null(df,col_name,action):
    df[col_name].fillna(df[col_name].agg(action), inplace=True)
    #alternative   
    #df[col_name].fillna(df[col_name].apply(action), inplace=True)
    return df

print (fill_null(df, 'D', 'mean'))
```

But if need `dropna` also:

```
def fill_null(df,col_name,action):

    if action == "dropna":
        df = df.dropna(subset = [col_name])
    else:
        df[col_name].fillna(df[col_name].agg(action), inplace=True)
    return df
```

Comment: for "df[col_name].fillna(df[col_name].agg(action), inplace=True)" getting output :AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'agg'

Comment: @Sidhartha - Then use some old version of pandas, is possible upgrade?

Comment: @Sidhartha - Function is implemented in pandas `0.20.0+`